# Multiple images height width validation not working in loop PHP

Tags: php, image

Hello i am trying to validate multiple images height width,I want if any uploaded image is not valid "height" and "width" then
"error" message should display,But Right now "Error" message showing even i uploaded "correct" image (valid image dimensions)
Here is my code,Where i am wrong ?

```
<?php 
$tf = array_filter($_FILES['banner']['name']);
$totalfiles = count($tf);
$final = $totalfiles + $oldimgcount;
        if ($final > 5) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('limit', "you cant upload more than 5 images");
            redirect('upload_controller/edit_store/' . $id, 'refresh');
        } else {
                if (isset($_FILES['banner']['name']) && $totalfiles != "0") {
                $totalfiles = count($_FILES['banner']['name']);
                $files = array();
                $target_path = "assets/store_banner/";
                $j = 0;
                for ($i = 0;$i < $totalfiles;$i++) {
                    $paths = 'assets/store_banner/';
                    $bannerpath = $paths . basename($_FILES['banner']['name'][$i]);
                   
                    $validextensions = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"); //Extensions which are allowed
                    $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['banner']['name'][$i])); //explode file name from dot(.) 
                    $file_extension = end($ext);
                   $target_path = $target_path.md5(uniqid()).".".$ext[count($ext) - 1]; //set the target path with a new name of image
                    $j = $j + 1;
                   
                    $maxWidth = 1920;
                    $maxHeight = 1080;
                    $imgs = $_FILES['banner']['name'];
                    $files[] = $paths . basename($_FILES['banner']['name'][$i]);
                    
                    $file_name = $paths . basename($_FILES['banner']['name'][$i]);
                    
                    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_name);
                    if ($width > $maxWidth || $height > $maxHeight) {
                         $this->session->set_flashdata('SizeError', "The image you are attempting to upload doesnt fit into the allowed dimensions.Image size must be 1080 x 1920 pixels.");
                        redirect('upload_controller/edit_store/' . $id, 'refresh');
                    }
                    if ($width < $maxWidth || $height < $maxHeight) {
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('SizeError', "The image you are attempting to upload doesnt fit into the allowed dimensions.Image size must be 1080 x 1920 pixels.");
                            redirect('upload_controller/edit_store/' . $id, 'refresh');
                    }
                
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'][$i], $bannerpath)) {
                            } else {
                            $j;
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "Something went wrong,Please try again later");
                            redirect('upload_controller/edit_store/' . $id, 'refresh');
                            }
                    }
        }
        
        
    ?>
```

Comment: `getimagesize($file_name)` - Is `$file_name` really a valid image path? Since you haven't moved the file yet, shouldn't it be `getimagesize($_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'][$i])`? Make sure that you show all errors and warnings while developing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: can you write exact code so i can check and implement in my side

Comment: I did do that though. Try changing `getimagesize($file_name)` to `getimagesize($_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'][$i])`. Not sure if that solves your issue, but currently you're checking the size of a non-existing image.